# There was a problem with reindexing process after Magento update

Tags: reindex, index, shell, product-prices

I have read several topics about this, but none if these topics seem to help me. I'm a beginner when it comes to Magento, so most of these topics don't really say much to me. I recently updated from Magento 1.6.2 to 1.9.2.1 and I noticed the following message:

```
One or more of the Indexes are not up to date: Product Prices. Click here to go to Index Management and rebuild required indexes.
```

Naturally, I went to Index Management and tried to reindex the only index that required reindexing: `Product Prices`.
After doing so, it showed this error: `There was a problem with reindexing process`

I've tried emptying the cache and locks folder and I also tried reindexing through shell with the command `php shell/indexer.php -reindexall`, which gave me the following errors below. I have no idea what to do, since I don't understand these errors.

```
Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Product Prices index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(133): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#7 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(48): OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#8 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->reindexAll()
#9 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#10 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#11 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `inner`.`entity_id`, `inner`.`customer_group_id`, `inner`.`website_id`, `inner`.`tax_class_id`, `inner`.`orig_price`, `inner`.`price`, `inner`.`min_price`, MAX(inner.max_price) AS `max_price`, `inner`.`tier_price`, `inner`.`base_tier` FROM (SELECT e.entity_id AS `entity_id`, pi.customer_group_id AS `customer_group_id`, cw.website_id AS `website_id`, pi.tax_class_id AS `tax_class_id`, pi.price AS `orig_price`, pi.final_price AS `price`, pi.final_price AS `min_price`, pi.final_price AS `max_price`, pi.tier_price AS `tier_price`, pi.tier_price AS `base_tier` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` ON l.parent_id = e.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id = l.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price_idx` AS `pi` ON ce.entity_id = pi.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON pi.website_id = cw.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0
 CROSS JOIN `cataloginventory_stock` AS `cis`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON cisi.stock_id = cis.stock_id AND cisi.product_id = ce.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 84 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 84 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id WHERE (e.type_id='configurable') ORDER BY IF(IF(cisi.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND cisi.manage_stock = 1,cisi.is_in_stock, 1), 1, 0) DESC, pi.final_price ASC, pi.price ASC) AS `inner` GROUP BY `inner`.`entity_id`,
        `inner`.`customer_group_id`,
        `inner`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`)' in /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(133): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(48): OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->reindexAll()
#8 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /home/users/spovnftp/sportinngerritsen.nl/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#13 {main}
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:21
Category Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (No such file or directory). Limited output.
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (No such file or directory). Limited output.
Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:07
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Default Values (MANAdev) index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Lucene Search Index index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

It really looks like your upgrade didn't fully run. It could *just* be that index table, but it's better to run the following (to be on the safe side).

**Do this on a dev environment first, and make sure you do files/db backups**

First thing you should do, is replace the `app/code/core` with a fresh install (make sure you don't have any local override in `app/code/local/Mage`). Same applies for `/lib`.

Then run the Magento Repair Tool to check your database: 
http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-repair-a-database-with-magento-repair-tool/

And fix any issue  that you can spot.

Answer (score 0):

Copy fresh downloaded Magento-1.9.2.1 \lib(all content) and  upload to magentoSite\lib (replace all or rename old lib for backup)